# Merge changes when pull breaks

Tags: git, merge, git-pull

The following situation: me and a colleague (or colleagues) work on the same file. I make some changes on my copy, a colleague also makes changes on their copy. They push, and when I pull - the pull breaks, because my copy of the file is different from the head. Even if I haven't changed anything that concerns the colleague's changes (f.e. I change in function A() and the colleague in function B()).

So in these cases I save my changes somewhere else, replace the file with HEAD Revision and only then I pull successfully and then apply back my changes. Another way I've seen is with the `Merge Tool` from the `Team` tab, but it still is a slow process of manually merging every single change.

My question is if there is a way to avoid these conflicts or when they occur - to merge the changes automatically?

Comment: Git is generally pretty good at automatically merging when two different parts of a file were modified. Can you provide any other information about what is happening? What tools are you using that contain a "`Merge Tool` from the `Team` tab"?

Answer (score 2):

One course of a merge hell could be multiple space/tab/newline changes. Consider following example: one of your colleagues uses editor, that replaces all tabs with spaces and you use an editor, that replaces all spaces with tabs. In this case you will be getting always tons of merge conflicts.

The solution to this problem is to use `-Xignore-all-space` options when merging:

```
git merge -Xignore-all-space
git rebase -Xignore-all-space
git pull -Xignore-all-space
```

Small changes that might not be immediately obvious (Thanks to @rbatt):

- **spaces** (can be fixed with `-Xignore-all-space`)
- **line endings** (see `core.autocrlf`, `core.safecrlf` and `core.eol` config attributes)
- **executable permission** (`chmod a+x ....`)
- **symbolic links vs. file copies** (`ln -s ...`)

Comment: Could line endings be another cause? Or permissions? +1 for the general notion of "small changes that might not be immediately obvious". There are line ending and chmod type options that could maybe help; I'm unsure though.

Comment: Thank you for contribution! I improved my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Git cannot decide if an automatic merge will break the compilability or even worse the semantics of your code.

Example:

you have a source file like this:

```
class A {
    //some Methods
}
```

if you add a method:

```
class A {
    methodA() {...}
    //some Methods
}
```

and your coleague adds a method:

```
class A {
    //some Methods
    methodA() {...}
}
```

You will end up in file like that (after automatic merging), which cannot be compiled since we have now two methods with the same name.

```
class A {
     methodA() {...}
    //some Methods
    methodA() {...}
}
```

This is the reason why always a human should verify the mergeresult. Using the mergetool is quite a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Git saves the modification as a generic patch. Since other people's work may add or reduce lines before the lines affected by your patch, Git cannot rely on line numbers to be the same when merging or rebasing. Git would, instead, try to determine the **context** of the change, which means it searches for the original lines you've changed (even if their location have changed), and checks if the leading and trailing 3 context lines remain the same. If other people changed the same function you have changed, there's no **safe** way to automatically merge the two changes, and in most cases human intervention is a good idea.

If you have recurring issues with merge conflicts where you only modify function A() and your colleagues modify function B(), try using the following parameter:

```
git pull -Xpatience
```